# error with RxDart, while combining two streams

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart

```
Stream<List<EntryJob>> get _allEntriesStream => Rx.combineLatest2(
        database.entriesStream(),
        database.jobsStream(),
        _entriesJobsCombiner,
      );

  static List<EntryJob> _entriesJobsCombiner(
      List<Entry> entries, List<Job> jobs) {
    return entries.map((entry) {
      final job = jobs.firstWhere(
        (job) => job.id == entry.jobId,
        orElse: () => null,
      );
      return EntryJob(entry, job);
    }).toList();
  }
```

I'm combining two streams jobs Stream and entries stream but the syntax showing errors and errors are shown in pic

[image: Here is the errors]

Comment: Do you *understand* the errors? Start with the simplest, the last error. Do you understand what is wrong?